# Android application stops working after clicking on TextView

Tags: java, android, textview

When I try to click on my `TextView` after setting the text, my application stops working.

```
textViewResult.setText("Children Name:\t" + child_name);

Intent intent = new Intent(welcome.this, gridview.class);
startActivity(intent);

create clickable textview
TextView tv = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.textViewResult);
tv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
    public void onClick(View v){
        Intent intent = new Intent(welcome.this, gridview.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```

Any advice?

Comment: What happans? Post the logcat info

Comment: Please post the logcat output. One reason could be that textView could be null. See if it is initialised properly.

Comment: Please add the crash logs.

Comment: need logcat and also your manifest file because  you have multiple gridview classes opening, one just before clickListener and other inside it. Maybe something to do with how your Gridview Activity is defined in manifest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probably your gridview.class is not added in manifest. After looking to your given piece of code and the behaviour you stated.

Comment: my bad, exactly was the problem. Thanks a ton